# CMSTreeView not working when upgrade kentico 9 to 10

Tags: kentico

I upgraded from Kentico 9 to 10 and it seems the CMSTreeView not working anymore. I also tried a simple example as this link but it didn't work :( : https://docs.kentico.com/k10/references/kentico-controls/cms-controls/cms-controls-navigation/cmstreeview

The error is : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Screenshot: [http://imgur.com/a/vjlgA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jkhO.png)

Any suggestion for this?

Thank a lot :)

Comment: Is the error you're receiving in custom code or within out of the box base Kentico code/modules?

Comment: It come from Kentico code

Comment: Then you need to provide some more info.  How did you do your upgrade?  Did it succeed?  Did it fail?  What messaged did you find in the event log after the upgrade?  What kind of customizations do you have to your install?  Check the log.txt file in the directory that holds the .sln file and make sure it has no errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check schema on your treeview (and on all your views) does not change even after the upgrade and is still the same  `dbo.`?

If you run upgrade script with another user (active directory?) it could change your schema and theoretical it could cause this kind of issue.